# C# UWP OpenWeatherAPI using mvvm

Tags: c#, api, mvvm, uwp

I'm trying to build a simple application in UWP that shows the current weather for my location.

I'm verry new to this. The problem is that I dont know where I should call the OpenWeatherAPI. Is it in the ViewModel? How do I show for example Temperature (Temp) from the CurrentWeatherForecast in my MainPage.xaml (my view) using ViewModel?

MainPage.XAML

```
`xmlns:weatherVM="using:UWPMM.ViewModels"
Loaded="Window_Loaded"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <weatherVM:WeatherViewModel>
        </weatherVM:WeatherViewModel>
    </Page.DataContext>
<Grid>
<Stackpanel>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Temp}"></TextBlock>`
```

Model named CurrentWeatherForecast. Here I also have patsted JSON as class from OpenWeatherMaps response.

```
    public async Task<RootObject> GetCurrentWeather(string lat, string lon)
    {
        var http = new HttpClient();
        var uri = String.Format(OpenWeatherUrl + "weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&units=metric&appid=" + OpenWeatherApiKey + "&mode=json");
        var response = await http.GetAsync(uri);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);

        return data;
    }
```

MainPage.XAML.cs

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GetCurrentPosition();
    }
    private async void GetCurrentPosition()
    {
        CurrentWeatherForecast currentWeatherForecast = new 
        CurrentWeatherForecast();

        var position = await LocationManager.GetPosition();
        string lat = position.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString();
        string lon = position.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString();
        await currentWeatherForecast.GetCurrentWeather(lat, lon);
     }
```

ViewModel named WeatherViewModel (Edited)

```
public class WeatherViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    CurrentWeatherForecast currentWeather;

    public WeatherViewModel()
    {
        currentWeather = new CurrentWeatherForecast();
    }
    private string _temp;
    public string Temp
    {
        get
        {
            return _temp;
        }
        set
        {
            _temp = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be some contradictions in your writing.

If you use ViewModel as the `DataContext` of Page, you need to create the `Temp` property in the ViewModel so that your binding will take effect. Or you can temporarily give up the ViewModel, we can simply handle the temperature display.

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<TextBlock x:Name="TempBlock" />
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TemperatureInit();
}
private async void TemperatureInit()
{
    CurrentWeatherForecast currentWeatherForecast = new 
    CurrentWeatherForecast();

    var position = await LocationManager.GetPosition();
    string lat = position.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString();
    string lon = position.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString();
    var tempData = await currentWeatherForecast.GetCurrentWeather(lat, lon);

    // Assign a value directly to the TextBlock
    TempBlock.Text = tempData.temp;
}
```

---

### Update

Here is MVVM way:

**ViewModel**

```cs
public class WeatherViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    CurrentWeatherForecast currentWeather;

    private string _temp;
    public string Temp
    {
        get { return _temp; }
        set
        {
            _temp = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public WeatherViewModel()
    {
        currentWeather = new CurrentWeatherForecast();
    }

    private async void TemperatureInit()
    {
        CurrentWeatherForecast currentWeatherForecast = new 
        CurrentWeatherForecast();

        var position = await LocationManager.GetPosition();
        string lat = position.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString();
        string lon = position.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString();
        var tempData = await currentWeatherForecast.GetCurrentWeather(lat, lon);

        this.Temp = tempData.temp;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<Page ...
    Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    >
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text={Binding Temp} />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new WeatherViewModel();
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var vm = this.DataContext as WeatherViewModel;
    vm.TemperatureInit();
}
```

Among them, the `OnPropertyChanged` function is used to notify the UI to change the display when the data changes.

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have actually already tried this but since I would like to display a lot of more weather related information I thought that the best practice would be using MVVM? How do I create the Temp property in the ViewModel? Appreciate all the help! =)

Comment: This works great! Thank you! =)
Lets say I want to also show Temp_min, Temp_max and WindSpeed. Do I just add this.Temp_min in the ViewModel?

Comment: Yes, you can add other properties you need just like adding the `Temp` property. Don't forget to add `OnPropertyChanged`. If my answer helps you solve the problem, please mark it as an answer, thank you :)